# How to display data in html form using ajaxcall

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have data like this.

js file

```
var numbers = 1234
```

Html file.

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id = "name">

<label>Id</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id = "id">
```

Requirement is:
whenever I enter my name in the first input box I want to display numbers from a javascript file into Id input box.

can we do with ajax call?

How to do that?

Comment: create keypress or change event for name input, inside of event add an ajax call, when result come set value to target

Comment: use Jquery if you need to make some simple interaction

Comment: why you need ajax for js file just use cdn

Comment: you have add your name in array and check onchange function that your name is present in array or not and then make a  ajax call after that feed the response to another input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want to insert a number into id textbox if you write something into name field, I am going to give you a sample example below:

**Note: you don't need ajax call for the event handling.**

```js
var numbers = 1234;

function myFunction() { //Modify this by your requirement
  var x = document.getElementById("id");
  if(document.getElementById("name").value != '') {
    x.disabled = true;
    x.value = numbers;
  } else {
    x.disabled = false;
    x.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id = "name" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<label>Id</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id = "id">
```

Comment: thanks amit it is working, whenever I enter name , Id field should be disabled and it should display that number

Comment: I have modified the code, you can check now. and if it is helpful then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help >

Your JS File Function:

```
function keypressCustom(){
   var enteredName = $("#nameFieldID").val();
   var IDValue = '';
   //Your Ajax Call Here

    $.ajax({url: "text_call_url", type: 'POST',  // http method
    data: { enteredName: enteredName }, success: function(result_id_value_from_ajax){
       IDValue = result_id_value_from_ajax;

       $("#idField").val(IDValue);
   }});

}
```

Your Html >

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="nameFieldID"  onkeypress="keypressCustom()" value=''>

<label>Id</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="idField"  value=''>
```